# WSO2 ESB LoadBalanced Endpoint Logging Target Endpoint

Tags: logging, wso2, load-balancing, endpoint

i'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.

In my usecase i use a proxy (MyProxy) sending each request towards a loadbalanced endpoint.
Inside the loadBalanced endpoint there are 3 endpoints (E1, E2, E3) and the balancing algorithm is the standard "round robin".
In this structure i need to log exactly:

1) Who is sendig the request (the client IP for example)

2) the payload of the request (maybe i can obtain this setting the log level = full)

3) which of the 3 endpoints the request is sent to (E1, E2 or E3 ?)

How can i achieve this?
thanx

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
 <log level="custom">
      <property name="Client IP" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
 </log>
```

2) Yes, you can use `<log level="full"/>`

3) I don't think you can achieve this using log mediator. As a workaround, if you enable DEBUG logs for your Endpoints (HTTPEndpoint, AddressEndpoint etc.), you can see to which endpoint each request is sent.